# Blank page when I try to comment, chat, or "like" something on Facebook

Tags: google-chrome, facebook

**Facebook**, navigating with **Google Chrome 15.0.874.121** and using **Ubuntu 11.10**, when i try to comment, chat or give a "like it" the next blank page appears and don't let me do anything:

http://www.facebook.com/ajax/ufi/modify.php

I've tried with, based on what i found in internet:

1. Erasing cookies and cache
2. desynchronize chrome before erasing it
3. Uninstalling chrome with: *sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable*
4. Erasing manually: */.config/google-chrome* directory

And nothings solves the problem, Any ideas, would appreciate your help

**Thanks**

Comment: did you tryed to navigate with https instead of http ?

Comment: Does the same thing happen in firefox?

Answer (score 3):

Visit https://www.facebook.com/ajax/ufi/modify.php instead. That URL requires use of [encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure) for security.

---

*from user [Micro](https://askubuntu.com/users/34541/micro)*